# Can I use freepik web element in website?

Tags: resource-recommendations, legal, html, licensing, stock-images

Can I convert PSD web elements like a pricing plan to HTML and use it free in the commercial website without attribution? 
for example this component : 
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Without knowing what the licence says, there's no way to answer this question. Contact the provider and ask them.  Also please don't ask for legal advice here. It's off-topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freepik employs different licenses. Sometimes you need to pay to use, even when attributing explicitly! The only way to be sure is to look at the license. If this is unclear, you need to contact Freepik.